# Existence of unique limit cycle for $r'=r(μ-r^2), \space θ' = ρ(r^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

**Exercise :**

> Translate the dynamical system given in polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates :
>   $$r' = r(μ-r^2)$$
>   $$θ' = ρ(r^2)$$
>   where $μ>0$ is a constant and $p: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$ smooth function with $ρ(μ) > 0$. Show that there exists a unique limit cycle. Would we have the same result if it was $ρ(μ) = 0$ ?

**Attempt :**

Using the relations :

$$x = r\cos(θ) \Rightarrow x' = r'\cos(θ) - r\sin(θ)θ'$$
$$y = r\sin(θ) \Rightarrow y' = r'\sin(θ) + r\cos(θ)θ'$$

I derived the equations for the given system in cartesian coordinates, as :

$$x' =  μx - yρ(x^2 + y^2) - x(x^2+y^2)$$
$$y' =  μy - xρ(x^2 + y^2) - y(x^2+y^2)$$

Now, regarding the limit cycle, if :

$$f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} μx - yρ(x^2 + y^2) - x(x^2+y^2) \\ μy - xρ(x^2+y^2) - y(x^2+y^2)\end{bmatrix}$$

How would I proceed about the limit cycle part of the problem though ? I know that one approach could be showing that $\text{div}(f) \neq 0$ for a simply connected set, but I'm not sure if this is correct and it seems that it wouldn't be leading anywhere since there is an unknown $ρ$ function there.

This is the first problem I'm trying to solve regarding that part of dynamical systems so I'd appreciate any help.

**What would I need to do to show the existence of a unique limit cycle ?**

Comment: If one wants to show that there exists a unique limit cycle, to translate the dynamical system to cartesian coordinates is definitely not the approach to turn to.

Comment: Just look at the phase portrait of the equation for $r$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Good morning and thanks a lot for your input ! Truly, the phase portrait revolves around the stationary point $r=0$ and conclusions can be made, but what would be the proper way of algebraically showing the existence and uniqueness of the periodic cycle?

Comment: The interesting point is not $r=0$ but $r=\sqrt{\mu}$!

Comment: @HansLundmark How would one draw a phase portrait when you have unknowns $μ, p(r^2)$ in your system ? Still, whats the theoritical/algebraic way to proceed ?

Comment: Never mind about $\rho$ to begin with, focus on the equation for $r$. Set the parameter to some value if that makes it easier for you. For example, take $\mu=4$ and draw the phase portrait on the $r$ line for the equation $dr/dt=r(4-r^2)$. (To get the general case afterwards, just erase “2” and write “$\sqrt{\mu}$” instead.)

Comment: @HansLundmark [Wolfram Phase Portrait](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7Br%284-r%5E2%29%2C+t%7D%2C+%7Br%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D). Seems like the phase portrait arrows act ike "bounded" from $-2$ to $2$ for example, which are the ranges of $\sqrt{μ}$ or is that a coincidence ?

Comment: That's not what is meant by the phase portrait of a *one-dimensional* system – that's something which is drawn on a one-dimensional *line*, not in a two-dimensional *plane*. (And the time variable $t$ is not involved.) You draw a number line, label it “$r$”, look at the sign of the right-hand side $r(4-r^2)$ to find out where $r(t)$ is increasing and decreasing, and then you indicate that by arrows: $$\longrightarrow \quad-\sqrt{\mu}\quad \longleftarrow \quad 0 \quad \longrightarrow \quad \sqrt{\mu} \quad \longleftarrow$$(except that here we don't really care about the region $r<0$).

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, that makes more sense ! So as $r(t)$ get's "bounded" around $\sqrt{μ}$ the existence is proved ! Now for the uniqueness, I guess it's a simple fact showing the monotony changes on the line or would it involve something more ?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks a lot for the help, I guess my mind was asking for something more complicated ! Thanks for leading me and making me figure it on my own!